# Xcode 7 - How to remove ld: warning: -read_only_relocs cannot be used with x86_64

Tags: xcode, warnings, twilio

I have recently updated to Xcode 7 and now receive the following warning when I compile:

ld: warning: -read_only_relocs cannot be used with x86_64

I don't think I changed anything in the build settings or code to create this. Does anyone know what is causing this warning and how to remove it?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build CMD+K then CMD+B.

Comment: Hi Ron - yes I have. I think I have found the problem. I'm using the Twilio API and it looks like it added this to the Other Linker Flags in Xcode. Not only does this generate the warning above (on the simulator) but it wont compile on an actual device because you can't have BYTECODE = YES and this flag.

Answer (score 7):

I have found the problem for those interested. As mentioned in the comment, I'm using the [Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios) and if you install this via cocoapods it adds the -read_only_relocs flag to the Other Linker Flags in Xcode (found under Build Settings). Not only does this generate the warning above (on the simulator) but it wont compile on an actual device because you can't have both BITCODE = YES and this flag. If you want to compile, you will need to set Enable Bitcode to No in the Build Options.

Comment: I'm wondering if you tried removing the flag?  Are there any side effects?

Comment: Good news everyone! We are aware of this issue and it will be fixed in the next version of Twilio Client (1.2.8). This version should be with you by the end of the week, so keep an eye out!

Comment: Hopefully this new version will also fix the duplicate SSL symbols (`ssl_lib.c.o`, `ssl_cert.c.o`, `ssl_session.c.o`) I am seeing when I combine Twilio with ooVooSDK2, and which causes linking to fail for the simulator (but not the device - that just crashes).

Comment: I'm using the Twilio Client version 1.2.11 and installed it via cocoa pods. But this issue still not fixed.