# No such module 'TwilioSDK' when importing as CocoaPod

Tags: swift, cocoapods, twilio

- XCode 7.2.1
- Swift 2
- CocoaPods 0.39.0

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'vent-ios-client' do
    pod 'TwilioSDK', ' ~> 1.2.0'
end
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278833/error-using-cocoapods-use-frameworks-swift) and [this](http://www.innerexception.com/2015/05/cocoapods-useframeworks-means-bridging.html) I don't need to create a Bridging-Header.h file or tweak my header search paths if I use `use_frameworks!`.  I should just be able to import the pod by it's name and it should work.

But all of the following result in "No such module" errors:

```
import TwilioSDK
import TCDevice
import TCDevice.h
import TwilioSDK/TCDevice
import TwilioSDK/TCDevice.h
```

Here is what the [TwilioSDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios) file structure looks like:

[image]

I am loading my project's .xcworkspace file.  And `pod install` completed successfully.

Comment: I ended up creating a bridging file and importing "TwilioClient.h" and then linked the Objective-C Bridging Header in the Swift Compiler - Code Generation settings and now it compiles.  But I thought I shouldn't have to do this?

Comment: Hey, thanks for reporting this. The Twilio Client team is looking into this now, but it looks like you'll need the bridging header for now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response philnash!  I'm finding another issue, a compile warning.  What's the best way to report this?  Write a question on SO?  Or should I submit a ticket through the Twilio support email?

Comment: I'm not that good with the Twilio iOS SDKs, but if you ask a question on SO then someone from the community may be able to help. At the same time, I can also check with our internal teams to see if they know about it tool. So I'd go with SO question. Tag it "twilio" and I'll see it too ;)

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like someone already asked it, but didn't tag it with twilio.  Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854874/xcode-7-how-to-remove-ld-warning-read-only-relocs-cannot-be-used-with-x86-6

Comment: Checking it out now!